# Textarea função php passar dados

Tags: php, html, funções

Tenho uma dúvida de como posso estar passando o valor de um textarea pra uma função do php.

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function _dup($cclist) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($cclist); $i++) {
                $ccnum = info($cclist[$i]);

                if (is_array($ccnum)) {
                        $cc = $ccnum['num'];
                        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($cclist); $j++) {
                                if (inStr(str_replace("-", "", str_replace(" ", "", $cclist[$j])), $cc))
                                        $cclist[$j] = "";
                        }
                }
        }

        foreach ($cclist as $i => $cc)
                if ($cc == "")
                        unset($cclist[$i]);

        $ok = array_values($cclist);
        return $ok;
}
```

E pra executar o script tenho essa outra função:

```
function check($ccnum, $ccmonth, $ccyear, $cccvv) {
        $ccline = $ccnum."|".$ccmonth."|".$ccyear."|".$cccvv;
        $action = new Run();
        $action->addToCart();
        $action->CCLINE = $ccline;
        return $action->checkOut();
}
```

O texarea vai receber o valor `nome|cpf|mae|data` pra que a função `check` possa fazer a sua validação.

```
HTML

<form action="" method=post name=f> <textarea wrap="off" name=cclist cols=90 rows=20> </textarea><br> <br> <input style="width:100px" class="button" type=submit name=submit size=10 value="Valida"> </form>
```

Comment: A textarea está num form?

Comment: <form action="" method=post name=f>
                <textarea wrap="off" name=cclist cols=90 rows=20>
</textarea><br>
                <br> <input style="width:100px" class="button" type=submit name=submit size=10 value="Valida">
        </form>

Comment: Edite sua pergunta colocando esse código (existe um botão editar logo aqui em cima)

Comment: Editada . poderia me ajuda agora ?

Comment: Seria só submeter o form para uma página em PHP que chamasse a função. Você já tentou isso?

Comment: Fica em branco .

Comment: Olá, não sei se isto foi apenas durante a crianção da pergunta, ou se fizeste o mesmo no script, mas coloque as `aspas` nos atributos `html`, e outra coisa é, onde é que a função `_dup` é chamada ? E qual a verdadeira função dela no script ? ^^ na verdade não sei do que se trata o código, mas tenho impressão que se trata de um filtro para certos dados digitados na `textarea`. Aguardo retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Sua duvida está confusa, mas respondendo à pergunta:

> como posso estar passando o valor de um textarea pra uma função do
>   php.?
>   Seria assim:

```
HTML

<form action="" method=post name=f>
<textarea wrap="off" name=cclist cols=90 rows=20> </textarea><br> <br>
<input style="width:100px" class="button" type=submit name=submit size=10 value="Valida"> 
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
function nomeFuncao(){
   $cclist =  $_POST['cclist'];
```

Depois para separar os valores *nome|cpf|mae|data* se eles estarão separados por | fica facil:

```
    $cclist_separados = explode("|", $cclist);
    print_r($cclist_separados);
}
```